# Dropping of "was" from "A couple of ministers had to resign too, among them [was] Interior Minister Fouchet."

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar, whiz-deletion, zero-copula

> A couple of ministers had to resign too, among them Interior Minister
>   Fouchet.

I don't know what type of rule is used to delete needed "was" in this sentence. My opinion is that "was" should be used like this.

> A couple of ministers had to resign too, (and) among them *was*
>   Interior Minister Fouchet.

Can someone tell me what rule is used to delete "was"? For example, be deletion, appositive, whiz deletion or etc?

Comment: The original is ok.

Comment: How come? Can you elaborate?

Comment: You _do_ realize that _was_ is **not** deleted because of a rule, but that a rule _may_ be formulated because this deletion happens?

Comment: How 'bout ***was deletion***? ;-)

Comment: The latter phrase is parenthetical to "ministers".

Comment: I think it's a slightly weird usage. If something/someone is *among* a number of similar things/people, that implies at least three, to my mind. So I would never say *Mars has two moons, among them Phobos*, for example. I can only accept the cited usage if I assume *a couple* is being used loosely to mean *a few [**probably** only two or three]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would not assume that this sentence indicates that exactly two ministers had to resign. Actually, if there were exactly two, I would expect the exact number to be mentioned. I read "a couple" here as "more than two, and less than any substantial number of the cabinet".

Comment: "A couple of is loosely used"; it could mean three. Damn native speakers.

Comment: @oerkelens: I see now I wasn't paying attention when I posted my comment. I meant to write *Mars has **a couple of** moons, among them Phobos*, where you don't (shouldn't?! :) have the option of assuming "a couple" is a loosely-defined "small number".

Answer (score 1):

There is a parenthetical involved here, and the internal grammar of parentheticals is often far more relaxed than within sentences proper.

> [Several] ministers had to resign too, among them Interior Minister
>   Fouchet.

A more logical ordering, clearly showing the parenthetical (subclass additional non-essential information) is:

> [Several] ministers, among them Interior Minister Fouchet, had to
>   resign too.

The length of the parenthetical is no doubt the reason why it is considered acceptable to postpose it: 'among them Bob Todd' would be less amenable to postposition. It appears illogical, but is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

> A couple of ministers had to resign too, among them Interior Minister
>   Fouchet.

I read it thus:

A couple of ministers had to resign too. Among them, Interior Minister Fouchet *had to resign*.

I don't see an implied 'was'.

Comment: But _all_ of _them_ had to resign, so it feels strange to single out Fouchet as having had to resign. It makes makes more sense to indicate that Fouchet was one of the ministers that had to resign, which means he _was_ among the minsters that had to resign.

Comment: Then it is two independent clauses combined together rather than a parenthetical phrase as Hot Licks suggested?

Comment: @oerkelens - The whole sentence is pretty awful anyway. Using 'among' with 'a couple' just sounds wrong. I think the whole thing needs to be rewritten. Unfortunately we aren't given that choice.

Comment: @mercyplease - I would say that I am agreeing with HotLicks (and disagreeing with oerkelens). The parenthetical version makes it clear that the verb is not 'was'.

Comment: What happens to chasly's parsing if we negate the statement? *A couple of ministers had to resign too, Interior Minister Fouchet not among them.*

Comment: I really fail to see what's awful about the sentence. _I bought some groceries, among which onions and tomatoes_ doesn't seem like too much of an outlandish sentence to me... but then again, maybe that's just me.

Comment: The one awkward thing is of course that _them_ semantically refers to _minsters that had to resign_, which is not actually present as an antecedent in the sentence. That has little to do with _some_ vs _among_, though.

Comment: In your interpretation, @chaslyfromUK, what does _them_ refer to? Ministers in general, or minsters _that had to resign_?

Comment: We mustn't get into a discussion within comments. I have to go now but I think there are some important points to address here so I'll return when I can and add to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence would undoubtably warrant the usage of a semi-colon.
Semi-colons are often used to replace a conjunction. You would be right in using a comma and then 'and', and a semi-colon can be used to replace this connective. So, you're sentence will be:

A couple of ministers had to resign, too; among them, interior Minister Fouchet.

You'll notice I added a comma before 'Interior'. This is simply for clarity. Spoken, this sentence would be read with a natural pause and so a comma is needed.